# Trying to save open MS Access documents from JScript

Tags: javascript, ms-access

I was hoping to save all open MS Access documents via a JScript run from the Windows Script Host.

So far I was able to obtain the MS Access object by calling:

```
var objAccess = GetObject('', "Access.Application");
```

But now I'm stumped. If it was MS Word, I'd enumerate all open documents in the .Documents property and call Documents.Item(n).SaveAs() method on each of them.

But how do you save-as all open documents in MS Access?

Comment: While Access is file based, it is not quite like other Office applications in that data is automatically saved. Back-ups are generally obtained by using copy, rather than Save As. Perhaps you could say a little more about what you wish to do?

Comment: I'm trying to automate saving of all open documents in our computer room before performing an installation of weekly updates and a later reboot. What puzzles me is that in the actual Access application there's an option to SaveAs, so why is there none in case of the automation script?

Comment: Save As is not suitable. You will need to ensure that users are not entering data (detect idle) and then close the Access instances. It gets a little more complicated if you have people working at development. Access is not the same as a document.

Comment: Thanks. You see my goal is not automate it, meaning that I need to close all open Access documents (or whatever it's called) and reboot the system, thus I cannot rely on a user interacting with it (in case Save As dialog comes up). So is there any way to do it with Access from a WSH script?

Comment: Save As dialog does not come up in Access. However, if users have objects open for design, they will need to be saved or abandoned. This is not a decision that can be taken lightly. What are your users likely to be doing with Access? Are you talking back-end (data) or front-end (forms etc)?

Comment: BTW Ways of making sure all users are safely out of an Access application usually involve a certain amount of coding in the application.

Comment: @Remou - "amount of coding" :) I appreciate your sarcasm but isn't it what I'm looking for. Or is it not the right forum for that?

Comment: :) I did not intend sarcasm, I meant in actually developing each Access application, not afterwards, as you need to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you have your object variable set to an Access application instance with GetObject, use its Quit method with the acQuitSaveAll option (value = 1).  Not sure about JScript; in VBScript, I can do it like this.

```
Dim objAccess
Set objAccess = GetObject(,"Access.Application")
WScript.Echo objAccess.CurrentDb.Name
objAccess.Quit(1) ' acQuitSaveAll
Set objAccess = Nothing
```

Note, when I used GetObject as in your example, objAccess was a *new* Access application instance rather than a reference to the instance which was running previously.  So, with the GetObject line like this ...

```
Set objAccess = GetObject('', "Access.Application")
```

... the WScript.Echo line threw an error with CurrentDb.Name (because there was not a database open in that Access application instance.

This approach will save any changes to database objects (tables, forms, reports, etc.) which were in design mode but not saved.  However if a user has any unsaved changes to data in a form, those changes will be discarded despite the acQuitSaveAll option.  It seems that option only applies to objects, not data.

**Edit**: If that approach is not satisfactory, you can do something more sophisticated with VBA in your Access applications, as @Remou mentioned in his comment.  An example is [KickEmOff](http://www.datastrat.com/Code/KickEmOff.txt) from Arvin Meyer.  He also offers a sample database which demonstrates that code in action.

**Edit2**: Remou's comment got me thinking acQuitSaveNone (value = 2) should be safer than acQuitSaveAll ... the unsaved object changes would be discarded, but at least you would be less likely to save an object in a non-functional state.

Comment: I would be pretty upset if a form was saved when I was working on design. It is possible that the form would then be unusable.

Comment: I'm unsure whether that's all you need.  As I read the question, GetObject seemed to get you the object references you need, so I took it from there.  I don't know about multiple user sessions on the server.  BTW, I'm more in favor of acQuitSaveNone ... if they don't save object changes before leaving at the end of the day, those changes can be discarded.

Comment: I get the methods, properties, and options from Access' online help.  In the VB Editor, position the cursor on a word and press F1 to bring up the related help topic.  Or type it into the search box (in the upper right of my VB Editor window --- dunno if the location is configurable).